# Redirect after login in mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In MVC, when writing a project, it writes a login scenario, the login screen, and the registry, and everything.

I created the admin page, but before you go to the page if I have not created a cookie, send me the login page. I want to do it after you log in. I do not know how to redirect to the admin page after logging in.

You have the code itself that writes the viewbag.retutnurl while you are building a project, but I do not know what the controller is.

Now I'm not sure where the value comes from.

If anyone knows exactly and done, please advise.

Comment: Are you using the generated authentication or your own?

Comment: I using the generated authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the default generated method change the first `case`, which executes when the login is successful, and add you custom redirection here like this:

```
switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin", null); // new code
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                    ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                    return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
            }
```

And in your admin class you should put the `[Authorize]` data annotation

```
//admin controller
 [Authorize]
 public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of these two ways to deal with it.

```
public ActionResult Index() {
     return RedirectToAction("AdminAction");
     //Or you can try this
     return RedirectToAction("whateverAction", "whateverController");
}
```

Comment: In mvc, when you create a project, it generates all login scenarios, even generates databases. It will set itself a redirect login to the home page and several returnUrl. It is not known where they are.
Now I want to change that value from the home page to the admin page
I do not want to change what I wrote myself because it is not Login ActionResult. This is Task <ActionResult>